# Saving R leaflet-shiny interactive map as HTML executable file

Tags: html, r, shiny, leaflet

Is there a way to save a leaflet-shiny script as a single executable HTML file? For example for a leaflet script you can use:

```
saveWidget(map, file = "mymap.html")
```

Then the html file will contain all the script and infromation that can be opened in a web browser and the script will run as in Rstudio.
This does not seem to work once shiny was integrated.

Comment: What else does your shiny app do? Most of the functionality that Shiny provides cannot be achieved without an active web server.

Comment: It is just an interactive map that I want to be able to launch from a local server and send the link to people so that they can view it.

Comment: That doesn't make things any clearer. A proper [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would help. But in general you cannot save shiny apps as an HTML web page. If that's your goal, you probably want to look into using a different tool.

Comment: Is there any new updated methods for this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. 
Below are listed the available options to deploy a Shiny App

https://shiny.rstudio.com/deploy/

The following also looks promising for what you are looking to do

Share as R scripts (assumes R Studio is installed)
https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson7/

Comment: Hi, do you know if there is any new method for this?